# Pylint gives error warning to working relative imports

Tags: python, import, pylint, streamlit

I have the following file structure:

```
├── README.md
├── apps
│   ├── fire_analysis.py
│   └── rois.py
└── streamlit_app.py
```

#### File contents

- streamlit_app.py

```py
from apps import fire_analysis
```

---

- apps/fire_analysis.py

```py
from .apps import rois
print(rois.the_object)
```

---

- apps/rois.py

```py
the_object = 42 # the object that I want
```

The code works just fine. But I am getting the `E0402: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package (relative-beyond-top-level)` error warning from pylint.

How to resolve this warning?
Am I doing the importing the wrong way in the `fire_analysis.py`?

Comment: Always  put the scripts that you are executing in the top folder of your project. The folder the script is placed in becomes the import base.

Comment: It is at the top of the project. I am executing `streamlit_run.py` file to import `fire_analysis.py` script and then the `rois.py` file is imported.

Comment: Then it's `from apps import rois`. The import base does not change for modules inside of packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me to change the import of `apps/fire_analysis.py` to

```
from . import rois
```

telling python to search locally.